# How can I convert this JavaScript to jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, local-storage

I'm trying to implement `localStorage` into one of my projects, but I'm having a problem because this portion of the code breaks my jQuery ui-layout.

```
function $(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

In order to make the layout work, I have to add a `$`:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
```

Being that I don't know how to write javascript or jquery, I can only implement it, can the code below be written in a way that I can avoid using the "function $(id)" part and the "$"?

Here is the code in its entirety:

```
// return value - this the prob?
function $(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

// write data to the local storage
function writeLocal() {
  var key = $('lsKey').value;
  var data = $('html').value;
  localStorage.setItem(key, data);
  updateItemsList();
}

// remove the item from localStorage
function deleteLocal(keyName) {
  localStorage.removeItem(keyName);
  updateItemsList();
}

// read the actual data for the key from localStorage
function readLocal(keyName) {
  $('lsKey').value = keyName;
  $('html').value = localStorage.getItem(keyName);
}

// allow retrieval of localStorage items
function updateItemsList() {  
  var items = localStorage.length;  
  var s = '&lt;p&gt;Saved Items&lt;/p&gt;';
  s+= '&lt;ul&gt;';  
  for (var i=0; i&lt;items; i++) {  
    var keyName = localStorage.key(i);
    s+= '&lt;li class="lsdLI"&gt;' + 
        '&lt;div style="float:right;"&gt;' + 
        '&lt;input onClick="readLocal(\''+keyName+'\');"/&gt;'+ 
        '&lt;input onClick="deleteLocal(\''+keyName+'\');"/&gt;'+
        '&lt;/div&gt;'+
        '&lt;b&gt;'+keyName+'&lt;/b&gt;' +
        '&lt;/li&gt;';
  }

  $('lsValues').innerHTML = s + '</ul>';
}

// start by loading up whatever is persistant in localStorage

function load() {  
updateItemsList(); 
}  
window.onload = load;
```

Comment: "Being that I don't know how to write javascript or jquery, I can only implement it" --- what?!

Comment: @zerkms, if you really didn't get it, it means `Ctrl+c, ctrl+v`. About the question, ah, so now jQuery is not JavaScript, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it sounds like you are using jquery UI and it's causing a conflict. Easiest thing to do might just be renaming the $ convenience function you are using...

```
// return value - this the prob?
function $$(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

// write data to the local storage
function writeLocal() {
  var key = $$('lsKey').value;
  var data = $$('html').value;
  localStorage.setItem(key, data);
  updateItemsList();
}

// remove the item from localStorage
function deleteLocal(keyName) {
  localStorage.removeItem(keyName);
  updateItemsList();
}

// read the actual data for the key from localStorage
function readLocal(keyName) {
  $$('lsKey').value = keyName;
  $$('html').value = localStorage.getItem(keyName);
}

// allow retrieval of localStorage items
function updateItemsList() {  
  var items = localStorage.length;  
  var s = '<p>Saved Items</p>';
  s+= '<ul>';  
  for (var i=0; i<items; i++) {  
    var keyName = localStorage.key(i);
    s+= '<li class="lsdLI">' + 
        '<div style="float:right;">' + 
        '<input onClick="readLocal(\''+keyName+'\');"/>'+ 
        '<input onClick="deleteLocal(\''+keyName+'\');"/>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<b>'+keyName+'</b>' +
        '</li>';
  }

  $$('lsValues').innerHTML = s + '';
}

// start by loading up whatever is persistant in localStorage

function load() {  
updateItemsList(); 
}  
window.onload = load;
```

It wouldn't be hard to convert what you have into jQuery either, but simply grabbing the first item out of each jQuery object.

```
// write data to the local storage
function writeLocal() {
  var key = $('lsKey')[0].value;
  var data = $('html')[0].value;
  localStorage.setItem(key, data);
  updateItemsList();
}

// remove the item from localStorage
function deleteLocal(keyName) {
  localStorage.removeItem(keyName);
  updateItemsList();
}

// read the actual data for the key from localStorage
function readLocal(keyName) {
  $('lsKey')[0].value = keyName;
  $('html')[0].value = localStorage.getItem(keyName);
}

// allow retrieval of localStorage items
function updateItemsList() {  
  var items = localStorage.length;  
  var s = '<p>Saved Items</p>';
  s+= '<ul>';  
  for (var i=0; i<items; i++) {  
    var keyName = localStorage.key(i);
    s+= '<li class="lsdLI">' + 
        '<div style="float:right;">' + 
        '<input onClick="readLocal(\''+keyName+'\');"/>'+ 
        '<input onClick="deleteLocal(\''+keyName+'\');"/>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<b>'+keyName+'</b>' +
        '</li>';
  }

  $('lsValues')[0].innerHTML = s + '';
}

// start by loading up whatever is persistant in localStorage

function load() {  
updateItemsList(); 
}  
window.onload = load;
```

Beyond those two options, you'd be looking at changing your code a bit more to truly do things the jQuery way. Instead of $('lsKey').value it would be $('lsKey').val(), etc. You'd have to update your code to use all the jQuery methods.

Comment: instead of `$('lsKey')[0].value;`, you should use `$('lsKey').val();` The getter methods always return the value from the first item in the jQuery collection

Answer (score 3):

You should define your functions first, then import the jquery library. You can then make this call

```
$.noConflict();
```

And it will keep the $ variable as it was before you imported jquery. After that, you can access jquery with the following:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
```

So you can use jquery's $ variable inside that function (or any function which you pass jQuery as the argument) and use your own $ variable outside.

You can read more on the topic here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/